# Advice on buying this car that has been in an accident

Tags: car, used, accident, buying

I'm thinking about buying something small and fast like the Golf GTI. I found this one, unfortunately, it has been in an accident. I need some advice on whether I should even consider buying it, your help is greatly appreciated!

To me it doesn't look like a big deal, I still know buying it would be a gamble, but the seller claims all parts that were damaged in any way were replaced and there has not been any damages on the engine itself.

Here are the pictures of the before accident and after restoration:

Pic1 before repair:
[image: Pic1 before repair]

Pic2 before repair:
[image: Pic2 before repair]

Pic3 after repair:
[image: Pic3 after repair]

Thank you!

Comment: Get the subframe alignment checked, unless you have some proof the repairers did that. Just "replacing the damaged parts" doesn't necessarily mean all four wheels want to drive in the same direction!

Comment: You should also determine if the car's registration has been changed because of the accident. We don't know where you are — the second pic suggests you're in the United States — and many jurisdictions change vehicle registration from "regular" to "salvage" (or similar) if the car has been in an accident. A "salvage" title may make obtaining insurance more difficult or impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take it to a car lot that has an identical vehicle and compare. I did this once and was shocked at the difference between a wrecked and non wrecked. Also obviously drive it and see if it tracks good and has no vibrations. Nothing wrong with buying a wrecked car if the repairs are done right